# Why am I getting an error message in Python 'cannot import name NoneType'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, porting

I'm trying to convert some code from 2 to 3 and the following simple script

```
import types
from types import NoneType
```

Results in

> ImportError: cannot import name NoneType

How can I convert the above from 2 to 3?

Comment: As there is only ever one instance of `NoneType`, `x is None` is exactly equal to `isinstance(x, NoneType)`. If you are checking type against `None`, something is wrong.

Comment: @GarethLatty It's useful for the tuple use case. `isinstance(json_compatible_basic_type_expected, (int, float, str, NoneType))`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no longer a `NoneType` reference in the `types` modules. You should just check for identity with `None` directly, i.e. `obj is None`. An alternative way, if you really need the `NoneType`, would be to get it using:

```
NoneType = type(None)
```

This is actually the exact same way `types.NoneType` was previously defined, before it was removed on [November 28th, 2007](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/918bbee3a545).

As a side note, you do not need to import a module to be able to use the `from .. import` syntax, so you can drop your `import types` line if you don’t use the module reference anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Fetching the `NoneType` is useful when performing validation, to abbreviate the chain of conditions passing the allowed `None` type in the tuple of acceptable types. So instead of writing something like:

```
a = {
    # A dict with some fields...
}

# In this example, the optional field is valid if it is a string
is_valid = (
    a.get(optional_field) is None
    or isinstance(a[optional_field], str)
)
```

One could write:

```
is_valid = isinstance(a.get(optional_field), (str, NoneType))
```

It is possible to work around this issue by passing a default string value to `.get(...)` (because in the absence of the field, you would be returning something that intentionally passes the validation, even if the value is not there), but it's too hacky, obscure and really affects readability.

As `NoneType` is not something you can import anymore, you can make your own when needed. These are some options:

```
NoneType = type(None)
NoneType = None.__class__
```

The linter may complain that a variable called `NoneType` doesn't comply with your naming convention, if you are following PEP8 recommendations. I find it easier to simply use `type(None)` wherever you need a `NoneType`. It's only two chars difference, just as readable and you save a line of code ;)

The final solution for the snippet above would look like:

```
is_valid = isinstance(a.get(optional_field), (str, type(None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use case allows it, you can:

```
if my_dict.get('key'):  # By Default: returns None if key doesn't exists
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something with None
```

None is a falsy value so you can get away with if-else statement without importing anything.